# Given a set of 1 to 100, what is the chance that a random and uniform subset has at most 2 elements?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We select a subset $\mathbf X$ of the set $\mathbf S =\{ 1, 2, ... , 100 \} $ randomly and uniformly (so that every set has the same probability of being selected). What is the probability that $\mathbf X$ has at most $2$ elements?

So, the total number of subsets of $\mathbf S$ is $2^{100}$. I need to figure out how to quantify the number of $2$ elements subsets and divide it by the powerset. I just can't figure out how to go about doing that though.

Comment: The number of $k$ element subsets is $\binom {100}k$.

Comment: So would it just be $\frac {\binom {100}2}{2^{100}}$?

Comment: Well, no.  you have to consider $k=0,1,2$.  The only subset with $0$ elements is the empty set.  There are $100$ subsets with exactly $1$ element and there are $\binom {100}{2}=\frac {100\times 99}2=4950$ subsets with exactly $2$ elements.

Comment: Ah, okay, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @lulu  You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested in the comments:

Given $k\in \{0,1,\dots,100\}$ the number of subsets of $S$ with exactly $k$ elements is given by the binomial symbol $\binom {100}k$.

Here, we are only interested in subsets with at most $2$ elements so we only care about $k=0,1,2$.  For $k=0$ we only get one subset (the empty set).  For $k=1$ each element is a subset, so there are $100$ such subsets.  For $k=2$ we get $\binom {100}2=\frac {100\times 99}2=4950$.  All together we get $5051$ subsets with $2$ or fewer elements. As the OP points out, there are $2^{100}$ subsets in total so the desired probability is $$\frac {5051}{2^{100}}\sim 3.98\times 10^{-27}$$  which is not a very large number.